# How to quickly print out all the properties in a NSObject and its derivatives?

Tags: ios

Say, I have an object of UIColor, can I quickly print out some debug information of its property information?

I need to print properties like red, blue, green components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just log a UIColor object like so:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
NSLog(@"%@",color);
```

It will output `UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1` which represents RGBA value of the color object. These numbers range from 0 to 1.

Comment: to add: more generally, this is controlled by the `description` method of an object. So you can apply it to your own classes as well.

Comment: sometimes you will find out print `debugDescription` is more useful

Answer (score 1):

For many objects you can simply use NSLog:

```
NSLog(@"The object = %@", someObject);
```

"Under the covers" this invokes the `description` method of "someObject", which for many objects (notably NSArrays and NSDictionaries) is quite descriptive, but for others, not so.

For your own classes you can override `description` to produce an appropriate string:

```
- (NSString*)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyClass{X = %d, Y = %d}", self.X, self.Y);
}
```